# How to remove duplicate serial numbers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have one BOM table in SQL Server 2012. I need to remove some middle layers because they have the same serial numbers. Following is the structure of current state and desired result. Can someone help in giving the SQL query or filter logic? See enclosed image for formatted table.

Current state:

```
Parent #    Child # Parent Name     Child Name 
----------------------------------------------
123        123  Sale SKU    Sale SKU
123        123  Sale SKU    PC Pack
123        123  PC Pack        Device
123        456  Device          LCD
123        789  Device           Kit
```

Desired state:

```
Parent #    Child #     Parent Name     Child Name 
--------------------------------------------------
123         123         Sale SKU        Sale SKU
123         456         Sale SKU        LCD
123         789         Sale SKU        Kit
```

Formatted table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBN5D.png

Comment: So you just want the "first" of the duplicates?  What determines that "Sale SKU" comes first?  Why Not "PC Pack"

Comment: What does your current SQL look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Telling a volunteer that your question is "urgent" is probably not going to get you the response you expect.

Comment: hi  D Stanley,  The first row which has parent # and child # same , is the top level row. That is the "Sale SKU" , which has the same parent , child number.  "PC Pack" is not in that category.

Answer (score 1):

You've not said what DBMS you're using so here's an oracle solution for deleting rows:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07ba2/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( Parent, Child,  Parent_Name, Child_Name ) AS
          SELECT 123, 123, 'Sale SKU', 'Sale SKU' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, 123, 'Sale SKU', 'PC Pack' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, 123, 'PC Pack',  'Device' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, 456, 'Device',   'LCD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, 789, 'Device',   'Kit' FROM DUAL;

DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Parent, Child ORDER BY NULL ) AS RN
    FROM   TEST
  )
  WHERE  RN > 1
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07ba2/1/0)**:

```
| PARENT | CHILD | PARENT_NAME | CHILD_NAME |
|--------|-------|-------------|------------|
|    123 |   123 |    Sale SKU |   Sale SKU |
|    123 |   456 |      Device |        LCD |
|    123 |   789 |      Device |        Kit |
```

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which RDBMS you are using but if it's `SQL SERVER` then you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get the desired data like

```
select [Parent #],
    [Child #],
   [Parent Name], 
   [Child Name]
from
(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Child #] ORDER BY [Child #]) AS rn
from mytable
) tab
where rn  = 1;
```